# Retrieve data presented on Solana Explorer page

Tags: rpc, metadata, api

I am wondering if there is any publicly available API to retrieve the data that is presented on the frontpage of https://explorer.solana.com such as live cluster stats and live transactions stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the explorer is Open Source you can find it [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/tree/master/explorer)

Answer (score 0):

The explorer is entirely fed by the JSON RPC API provided by validator nodes.  So every piece of functionality is supported by calls to the methods at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api